# Issue with nested if statement (within function) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

first time here and I've run into an issue... idk if it's my syntax or my logic is completely wrong...

```
var hasExperience;
var amountOfExperience;

function employed(hasExperience,amountOfExperience) {

  if(hasExperience === true){
    if(amountOfExperience > 5)
      return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem to want to return false if the first two if statements aren't met... anyone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: You could write `return hasExperience  && amountOfExperience > 5`. ;-) Your code will only return false if  `hasExperience !== true`, otherwise it may return true or undefined (and `undefined !== false`).

Comment: if(hasExperience != true && parseInt(amountOfExperience) < 5){
    return false;
  }

Comment: @Suresh—the less than operator `<` uses the [*abstract relational comparison algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) which coerces the operands to number, so *parseInt* won't make any difference here.

Comment: or just have no else ... and return false as the final statement in the function

Comment: `return hasExperience === true && amountOfExperience > 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need both of the if statements to evaluate to `true`, you should write it like this:

```
if(hasExperience === true && amountOfExperience > 5){
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

In your example, `if(hasExperience === true)` then you run the code inside the if block, `else` run the code inside the else block. It's important to understand that this is completely independent of what's inside the `if` block.

```
if(hasExperience === true){
    // code inside if block
} else {
    // code inside else block
}
```

The code inside the `if` block happens to be another `if` statement that will `return true` `if(amountOfExperience > 5)`, and does nothing otherwise. Again, this is independent of the other `if` statement.

```
if(amountOfExperience > 5)
    return true;
```

Using `&&`, means that both statements have to evaluate to `true` in order to execute the code inside of the `if` block. You can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

---

Also, as some others have stated, you can just write your function like this:

```
function employed(hasExperience,amountOfExperience) {
    return hasExperience === true && amountOfExperience > 5;
}
```

Since your evaluating `(hasExperience === true && amountOfExperience > 5)` as a boolean and returning that boolean, you can avoid the `if` statement all together.

Try experimenting with this a little bit more to understand what's going on.

---

Update based on comment:

You could also accomplish this using the nested if, but this makes the code messy and difficult to read.

```
if (hasExperience === true) {
    // only hasExperience is true
    if (amountOfExperience > 5) {
        // hasExperience is true and amountOfExperience is greater than 5
        return true;
    } else {
        // hasExperience is false and amountOfExperience is less than 5
        return false;
    }
} else {
    // hasExperience is false and we have no idea what amountOfExperience is
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `return hasExperience === true && amountOfExperience > 5`

Comment: The problem asks for both being true using a nested if statement, is there a way to prove both instances are correct, and if not return false? Also, thank you for all the help!